# stdout missing while using psexec in golang

Tags: go, psexec

On remote machine I just used psexec.exe to run specific command, the output of the cmd is intact while testing in shell.

Only the first line was printed out when submitting the cmd in Golang.

I tried to use winexe on linux platform, but the Symantec anti-virus treats it as PUA, then I turned back to windows platform.

```
func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("C:\\Users\\v\\go\\src\\asys\\ss\\psexec.exe", "\\\\192.168.0.64",  "-nobanner", "-accepteula", "-u", "vz", "-p", "1",  "-s", "cmd", "/c", "ipconfig")
  var out bytes.Buffer
  multi := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &out)
  cmd.Stdout = multi
  if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("\n*** FULL OUTPUT *** %s\n", out.String())
}
```

output:

```
Windows IP Configuration
*** FULL OUTPUT ***
Windows IP Configuration
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: «the output of the cmd is intact while testing in shell»—are you sure? I mean, if you run `psexec.exe ... blah blah` >NUL` (that is, redirect stdout to the `NUL` device), would the output be gone?

Comment: @kostix yes, the output be gone if >NUL; in shell, if  > 1.txt, the file 1.txt will contain full contents of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Not to answer your question directly, but I'm afraid you might be falling victim of the so-called [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378): there's no point in jumping through that many hoops to merely collect an information about the configuration of the IP stack of the target host—Windows provides special means, called [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation), to carry out such tasks.

So, instead of calling `psexec.exe` to call—on the target host—`cmd.exe` to call `ipconfig.exe`, you may just defer this task to one of the queries supported by WMI.

I'd suggest using either `Win32_NetworkAdapter` or `Win32_IP4RouteTable` (or both)—depending on which kind of data you actually need (configuration of NICs or routing data).

A working sample, using [`github.com/StackExchange/wmi`](https://github.com/StackExchange/wmi) is:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/StackExchange/wmi"
)

type win32_NetworkAdapter struct {
    AdapterType string
    AdapterTypeID uint16
    AutoSense bool
    Availability uint16
    Caption string
    ConfigManagerErrorCode uint32
    ConfigManagerUserConfig bool
    CreationClassName string
    Description string
    DeviceID string
    ErrorCleared bool
    ErrorDescription string
    GUID string
    Index uint32
    InstallDate time.Time
    Installed bool
    InterfaceIndex uint32
    LastErrorCode uint32
    MACAddress string
    Manufacturer string
    MaxNumberControlled uint32
    MaxSpeed uint64
    Name string
    NetConnectionID string
    NetConnectionStatus uint16
    NetEnabled bool
    NetworkAddresses []string
    PermanentAddress string
    PhysicalAdapter bool
    PNPDeviceID string
    PowerManagementCapabilities []uint16
    PowerManagementSupported bool
    ProductName string
    ServiceName string
    Speed uint64
    Status string
    StatusInfo uint16
    SystemCreationClassName string
    SystemName string
    TimeOfLastReset time.Time
}

type win32_IP4RouteTable struct {
    Age int32
    Caption string
    Description string
    Destination string
    Information string
    InstallDate time.Time
    InterfaceIndex int32
    Mask string
    Metric1 int32
    Metric2 int32
    Metric3 int32
    Metric4 int32
    Metric5 int32
    Name string
    NextHop string
    Protocol uint32
    Status string
    Type uint32
}

func main() {
    var compName string
    switch len(os.Args) {
    case 1:
        compName = "."
    case 2:
        compName = os.Args[1]
    default:
        log.Fatalf("usage: %s [COMPUTER]", os.Args[0])
    }

    var dst []win32_NetworkAdapter
    //var dst []win32_IP4RouteTable
    q := wmi.CreateQuery(&dst, "")
    err := wmi.Query(q, &dst, compName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%#v\n", err)
    }

    for _, v := range dst {
        log.Printf("%#v\n", v)
    }
}
```

As presented, it queries the host whose name is passed on the command line (or, missing that, localhost) for the NIC config.

To get routing data instead, comment out the first `var dst ...` statement and uncomment the second one.

The relevant starting points are [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter)
and [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmiiprouteprov/win32-ip4routetable).

Comment: actually beyond ipconfig i need to collect installed software by using Get-WmiObject -Class win32reg_addremoveprograms, i did use wmic to collect before, but it's slow and not as completed as what the powershell got

Comment: `wmic` provides only a limited view into WMI. Try getting the docs on `win32reg_addremoveprograms` and call it via plain WMI.

Comment: thanks for your reply. what you said is one of the command i did at the beginning:
psexec \\hostname -nobanner -u admin -p 123456 /s cmd /c %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Get-WmiObject -Class win32reg_addremoveprograms "|" select Displayname, version, installdate

Comment: coz the target machine could be firewall-enabled, then i tried to run the query locally after landing on the target machine via psexec

Comment: @zeng-vincent, hmm, do you think `psexec` uses some sort of firewall-evading magic which allows it to talk to the target host without using a network connection? ;-) No way, pal, — in the end, it uses TCP/IP as well.

Comment: the powershell remoting query needs additional config in remote machine, i dont want to make any changes in remote machine before i can remote to it  :)

Comment: I have never suggested using PowerShell remoting. I suggested using matching WMI queries.